Jenkins Thin Backup: A problem occurred while processing the request
I ran into this error while trying execute Thin backup in Jenkins.
I tried reading the logs below but didn't quite get it.
Jun 20, 2024 2:53:59 AM WARNING org.jenkinsci.plugins.periodicbackup.PeriodicBackup execute
Could not parse given cron tab! line 1:0: mismatched input '' expecting {TOKEN, '', '@', 'H'}
Jun 20, 2024 2:54:59 AM WARNING org.jenkinsci.plugins.periodicbackup.PeriodicBackup execute
Could not parse given cron tab! line 1:0: mismatched input '' expecting {TOKEN, '', '@', 'H'}
Jun 20, 2024 2:55:59 AM WARNING org.jenkinsci.plugins.periodicbackup.PeriodicBackup execute
Could not parse given cron tab! line 1:0: mismatched input '' expecting {TOKEN, '', '@', 'H'}
Jun 20, 2024 2:56:59 AM WARNING org.jenkinsci.plugins.periodicbackup.PeriodicBackup execute
Could not parse given cron tab! line 1:0: mismatched input '' expecting {TOKEN, '', '@', 'H'}
Jun 20, 2024 2:57:59 AM WARNING org.jenkinsci.plugins.periodicbackup.PeriodicBackup execute
Could not parse given cron tab! line 1:0: mismatched input '' expecting {TOKEN, '', '@', 'H'}
Jun 20, 2024 2:58:59 AM WARNING org.jenkinsci.plugins.periodicbackup.PeriodicBackup execute
Could not parse given cron tab! line 1:0: mismatched input '' expecting {TOKEN, '', '@', 'H'}
Jun 20, 2024 2:59:59 AM WARNING org.jenkinsci.plugins.periodicbackup.PeriodicBackup execute
Could not parse given cron tab! line 1:0: mismatched input '' expecting {TOKEN, '*', '@', 'H'}
Jun 20, 2024 3:00:59 AM WARNING org.jenkinsci.plugins.periodicbackup.PeriodicBackup executeenter image description here
